# How to show a sliding side bar using keyframes of css in React

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, sidebar, keyframe

Right now I am having an issue with make a sliding side bar using react.

I know there is a lot of react libraries that makes a sliding bar pretty easily, but what i want right now is like a sliding bar that pushes a main section with a toggling button.

simply, if the button is clicked, split a content as 75% for main and 25% for sidebar. and I would like to have an animation too using key frames maybe.

here is the image of what i am trying to achieve.
[image]

[image]

So I used bootstrap initially as code below.

```
const [isNoteOpen, setIsNoteOpen] = useState(false, []);

  const onClickBtn = (e) => {
    setIsNoteOpen(!isNoteOpen);
    console.log(isNoteOpen);
  };

  const btnStyle = {
    position: "fixed",
    top: "7rem",
    right: "3rem",
    zIndex: "1",
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex">
      <button
        style={btnStyle}
        className={`btn float-right round-box ${(isNoteOpen && "btn-primary") || "btn-danger"}`}
        onClick={onClickBtn}
      >
        &lt;
      </button>

      <div className="d-flex w-100 mx-0 mx-md-5">
        <div className={`note-transition pr-3 pl-2 ${isNoteOpen ? "w-75" : "w-100"}`}>
          <div className="">
            <img className="img-fluid w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>

          <div className={`pl-3 pr-2 ${isNoteOpen ? "w-25" : "d-none"} `}>
          <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <div className="border w-100" style={{ height: "100px" }}>
              PLACEHOLDER
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

style.css

```
.note-transition {
  transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
}
```

When I close the side bar is fine, however, when I open the side bar, it all of sudden appears out of nowhere.
then I wanted to apply keyframe to make animation so that i thought it would not appear suddenly. However I have no idea how to make it work.

I would appreciate if anyone could provide me how to achieve this. and if you know any other solution which is more elegant or efficient, kindly let me know too for my future reference.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [way to achieve what you need](https://jsfiddle.net/7xbakce8/33/).

Smooth transitions should be done only on "transform" and "opacity" CSS attributes.
If you do this on other attributes, you will face a recalculation of the layout and it will be slower.
You may not notice this on a powerful desktop computer, but you can experience janks on mobile phones.

What we want is this:

```
<div class="show-navbar">
  <article>...</article>
  <navbar>...</navbar>
<div>
```

When `show-navbar` class is set, we want to see the full `<navbar>` on the right.
But when `hide-navbar` is set, we want this `<navbar>` to be hidden smoothly out of the screen.

You can achieve this with this CSS code:

```
#my-component.show-navbar > navbar {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

#my-component.hide-navbar > navbar {
  transform: translateX(var(--navbar-size));
  transition: transform .3s;  
}
```

The problem is now that the **width** of `<article>` must change because we don't want the right panel to prevent us to see the content of `<article>`.
So we must tell CSS that this transition is not to be smooth.

```
#my-component.show-navbar > article {
  right: var(--navbar-size);
  transition: right .3s steps(1, end);
}

#my-component.hide-navbar > article {
  right: 0;
  transition: none;
}
```

When we transition to **hide-navbar** we want `<article>` to expand immediately.
But when we transition to **show-navbar** we want it to shrink at the end of the 300 ms. That's why we use the time-function **`steps()`**. See the [doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function).